# Detect Disappearing All Cell Before ViewController Dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can i detect the cells are disappearing before viewcontroller (tableview) disappear.
I want to stop audioplayer before viewcontroller dismiss.Each custom cell has a audioplayer property.

So i need to a delegate that is like viewwilldisappear but in my customcell class.How?

EDIT : 
dealloc not hitting or hits after 5-10 second after disappearred.

didenddisplayingcells method not working!

Comment: you might be knowing when viewcontroller gets dismissed which is being triggered by button's action (like something). So maintain a flag like stopAnyPlayer in cell's property which should be YES and reload tableview first for stopping all player in all cells if playing.

Comment: you can stop your player in viewDidDisappear method

Comment: there is no method for uitableviewcell viewdidDisappear!

Comment: each cell have own player.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     for (HBCarouselViewCell * cell in self.carouselItemView.visibleCells) 
     {
         [cell.mediaView setMediaMovieMuted:YES];
     }
```

}

self.carouselItemView - collection view

mediaView - property in the cell, who can stop playing music/video

but it's only for visible cells.